# Equations of motion/ Boundary conditions in presence of defect

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, boundary-conditions, variational-calculus, boundary-terms

Cosider the following Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} = \Theta(-x) \left( \frac{1}{2} (\partial\phi_1)^2 - V_1(\phi_1) \right) + \Theta(x) \left( \frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi_2)^2 - V_2(\phi_2) \right) + \delta(x) \left( \frac{1}{2} (\phi_1 \partial_t \phi_2 - \phi_2 \partial_t \phi_1) - \mathcal{B}(\phi_1,\phi_2) \right) $$

where $\mathcal{B}$ is a function of the fields but not derivatives thereof.

Then one should get the following set of equations

$$\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\partial^2\phi_1  &= -\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial \phi_1} \,, &&x <0\\
\partial^2\phi_2  &= -\frac{\partial V_2}{\partial \phi_2} \,, &&x >0\\
\partial_x \phi_1 - \partial_t \phi_2 &= - \frac{\partial  \mathcal{B}}{\partial \phi_1} \,, &&x = 0\\
\partial_x \phi_2 - \partial_t \phi_1 &= \frac{\partial  \mathcal{B}}{\partial \phi_2} \,, &&x = 0 
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

The first two are clearly just the bulk equations of motion, but I can't see how to get the last two. In particular I do not see where the $\partial_x \phi_i$ comes from, since from a naive application of Euler-Lagrange, I  just get

$$\partial_t \phi_2 = \frac{\partial \mathcal{B}}{\partial \phi_1} \quad \text{at} \ x=0$$

Comment: Hint: It comes from $x$-differentiation of the step function.

Comment: Of course, I totally forgot about that - thank you!